# Can someone please tell me what's wrong with this code?

Tags: c++, function, program-entry-point, itoa

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void OpCode()
{
    string mnemonic;
    int hex;
    char *op;

    cout << "Entre mnemonic : ";
    cin >> mnemonic;

    char *str1 = strdup(mnemonic.c_str());

    if(strcmp(str1, "ADD") == 0)
    {
        hex = 24;
        itoa(hex,op,16);
        cout << op;
        cout << "\nEqual";
    }
    else
    cout << "\nFalse";
}

int main()
{
    OpCode();
    return 0;
}
```

It runs till the part where I use the op variable, I tried copying and pasting in the main function it worked perfectly, why wouldnt it work in OpCode function?! Thanks in advance

Comment: You're stomping over memory that's not yours. Now's a good time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Hint: why did you use strdup on the variable `str1`? And why aren't you doing the same on `op`?

Answer (score 1):

`itoa` writes into memory pointed to by its second argument. It does not allocate that memory itself. This means its up to you to pass it a valid memory pointer. You're not; you never allocate any memory. It worked when in main by luck not design.

A simple way would be to replace line where you define `op` to `char op[9];` but remember that this is locally allocated memory so you couldn't return it from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix with a comments

## include

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void OpCode()
{
    string mnemonic;
    int hex;
    char op[10];  // allocate a pointer op that points to 10 empty spaces of type char.

    cout << "Entre mnemonic : ";
    cin >> mnemonic;

    char *str1 = strdup(mnemonic.c_str());

    if(strcmp(str1, "ADD") == 0)
    {
        hex = 24;
        itoa(hex,op,16);   // convert hex to an ASCII representation and write the ASCII to the 10 empty spaces we allocated earlier.
        cout << op;
        cout << "\nEqual";
    }
    else
    cout << "\nFalse";
    free (str1); // free the memory that was allocated using strdup so you do not leak memory!
}

int main()
{
    OpCode();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do not use strdup in the first place as you should check the return value may be null if there is not enough memory to duplicate the string.

Comment: to print the hex value of a number or integer just use printf !!